# Forma correcta de ejecutar update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber si la forma en la que estoy consultando mi base de datos es la óptima o cual de las 2 alternativas es la mas óptima:

***conexión:***

```php
$bd = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "clave", "basededatos");

// Mi for y mis consulas
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
  $bd->query("update productos set stock = stock - 10 where id = ".$i);
}
    
$bd->close();
```

Ahora bien esto me va perfecto pero estuve leyendo que cada consulta debería ser cerrada y lo único que se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

```php
// Mi for y mis consulas
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  $bd->query("update productos set stock = stock - 10 where id = ".$i);
  $bd->close();
}
```

Tengo esta duda ya que mi proveedor de servicios me dice que mi sistema tiene poco rendimiento ya que muestra demasiadas consultas.

Nota: este `for` es solo un ejemplo y la consulta también lo realmente importante es el cierre de mi consulta.

Comment: De las dos que muestras la más óptima es la primera. En la segunda estarías cerrando la conexión dentro del bucle, cuando aún la necesitas, lo cual sería absurdo y daría error en la segunda interacción del bucle, porque no habrá conexión para seguir actualizando. Dicho eso, la primera forma no es la más óptima de todas. Es mejor preparar una sola consulta con todas las actualizaciones y ejecutar una sola vez, o bien usar transacciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes todas la razón como vez mi respuesta y sobretodo el enlace que coloco al final, yo creo que le puede llegar a venir bien :-)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya creo que OP no pregunta por la sintaxis de la instrucción `UPDATE`, creo que su duda más que nada es si cerrar la conexión o no. Realmente es un problema ficticio, porque aquí lo esencial no es si cerrar o no cerrar (la conexión se cerrará cuando el script termine, a no ser que sea una conexión persistente). Y la optimización está en ejecutar `N` consultas llamando a `query()` o ejecutar una sola o usar transacciones. Pero para responder a todo esto faltan detalles, como el engine en que está la BD, si usa `mysqli` o `PDO` en este contexto, etc.

Comment: Parece absurda mi pregunta pero tienen toda la razon si cierro una conexion ya no podre ejecutar otra consulta, gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: @AndreMateoChavez Si lees mi respuesta, te he dado una opcion de ahorrarte el problema que comentas de las abundantes consultas.

Comment: @adrigo si lo entendi amigo lo que pasa es que es solo un ejemplo en realidad no recorro con for para obtener los id solo quise ejemplificar un bucle

Comment: @AndreMateoChavez La idea de StackOverflow es dar ejemplos con los que podmaos ayudarte, si estas diciendo que haces muchas peticiones y das un ejemplo con un for, te ayudamos a quitar el for.... Si no es tu caso no podemos ayudarte al respecto... Si te das cuenta todas las respuesta van enfocadas al for...

Comment: @adrigo formule una pregunta con mi problema amigo, me serviria mucho tus conocimientos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/533355/preparar-consulta-update-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Si cierras la conexión dentro del `for`, no podras realizar un segundo update si no vuelves a iniciar la conexion dentro del `for`, ya que la conexion estaria cerrada, valga la redundancia.

Aunque hagas la conexion dentro del `for`, el problema especificado por tu proveedor de servicios persistirá ya que seguirás realizando la misma cantidad de peticiones porque sigues teniendo el mismo `for`.

Una forma de ahorrarte hacer 10 peticiones, es hacer una sola que contenga todos los UPDATEs, te pongo un ejemplo:

```sql
UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - 10 WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 9;
```

Este caso que te he puesto sería exactamente lo mismo que tu `for`, pero sería estatico y tendrías que amoldarlo para que fuera dinámico, de todas formas actualiza 10 lineas de la DDBB con una sola UPDATE, ahorrandote 9 peticiones.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de usar un **UPDATE** es :

```
UPDATE tabla
SET columna='valor' WHERE columna='comprobacion'
```

Y de tus programas esta seria mas optima ya que la segunda cierra la conexión dentro del bucle por lo que te daría error seguramente.

```
$bd = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "clave", "basededatos");

// Mi for y mis consulas
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
 $bd->query("update productos set stock = stock - 10 where id = ".$i);
}

$bd->close();
```

[Mas informacion de PHP con UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)