# Preparar consulta update mysql

Tags: php, mysql

vengo realizando unas consultas a mi base de datos para descontar el stock segun mi array pero tengo entendido que esta forma no es la mas obtima y que seria mejor hacerlo con consultas preparadas principalmente por un tema de rendimiento ya que mis variables son estrictamente validadas.

Yo lo vengo haciendo asi:

```
$productos = array(
    array(1,10),
    array(2,25),
    array(3,35),
);

foreach($productos as $producto){
    $bd->query("UPDATE productos set stock = stock - $producto[1] WHERE id_producto = ".$producto[0]);
}
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo en realidad hay mas cosas de por medio pero basicamente esta es la idea del array

Mi pregunta es: cual seria la forma mas optima de realizar la misma consulta update con un procedimiento almacenado o consulta preparada ?

Nota: se que una mejor opcion seria usar triggers o disparadores pero tengo unas razones por las cuales no puedo incorporarlo a mi sistema.

Comment: Toma algunos [ejemplos](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: Echa un ojo a [Insert on duplicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) de mysql, documentacion oficial. Tambien te puede ayudar [updating multiple rows with different values in one query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69269/updating-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query) o [mysql update multiple rows with different values in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query)

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu comentario pero esto me ahorra lineas de codigo mas no es un procedimiento que mejore el rendimiento al realizar el mismo update varias veces

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *mis variables son estrictamente validadas*? Pregunto porque las consultas preparadas no sirven sólo para optimizar, sino también para proteger contra *inyección SQL*. Aunque tus variables sean validadas, si usuarios externos las proporcionan, el riesgo de *inyección* es altísimo, ya que estarías pasando a `query()` **cualquier cosa**, incluyendo **código dañino**. Dicho eso, hay otro aspecto que puede ayudar a optimizar y a la vez controlar los cambios, me refiero a las transacciones. Conviene usarlas para modificar datos masivos, pero eso depende del engine de la BD.

Comment: @AndreMateoChavez nose si me respondes a mi o a javier.

Comment: @A.Cedano con estrictamente validadas me refiero a que mediante expresion regular solo muestro caracteres permitidos previamente; si solo quiero filtrar numeros uso [0-9] y ademas de ello elimino barras invertidas, lo mismo para texto, fechas y demas. es por ello que la inyeccion no es un problema. Nota: no permito codigo html en ningun aspecto

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu enfoque está bien como punto de partida. El tema que veo optimizable sería generar una tabla extra en PHP con el resumen de movimientos por `id_producto` **sólo en el caso de que habitualmente se repitan**.
Quiero decir... si tienes algo como

```
$productos = array(
    array(1,10),
    array(2,25),
    array(3,35),
    array(2,40),
    array(2,55),
    array(1,15),
    [...]
    array(1,10),
    array(1,30),
);
```

podrías hacer un recorrido del array para generar uno de **resumen**, cuyo resultado podría ser

```
$resumen_productos = array(
    array(1,245),
    array(2,320),
    array(3,95)
)
```

Y entonces pasar a las actualizaciones de la Base de Datos desde este Array y no desde el original.
Así se harían muchas menos actualizaciones. Es cierto que a cambio hay que recorrer el array en PHP y crear otro, pero es bastante más rápido según mi opinión.

Espero haberme explicado y que te/os sirva, al menos para el debate.

Comment: Es mejor preguntar que suponer.

Comment: si claro esto si lo tengo implementado, sumo todos mis array y genero un array nuevo con las sumas ya hechas, pero el sentido de mi optimización va por el lado de las consultas a la base de datos